# clean project Mechanism Android

Tags: android

what is advantage or magic or mechanisum behind clean project?

some time we implement code which are not effect in final output and we are clean `(: from:  project Explorer  >>  clean :)` it and as per expected output are in front of us.some time R.java are also not take resource and as we clean it it going to right way.

**how clean is different from buildup ?**

so now i would like to know Mechanism behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how clean is different from buildup ?

Cleaning a project gets rid of already-compiled classes, forcing a full recompile of all of your classes.

In Android development, this sometimes clears up a problem where the `R.java` generated class gets recompiled with new resource IDs, but the previously-compiled classes (where the various numeric constants from R get inlined in the bytecode) do not get recompiled to reflect the same changes.